# Bluetooth wont turn on....add info as req

Tags: bluetooth

Screenshot reflecting conflicting bt status

Fresh dualboot 20.04lts / win010 install on E6520 i7 win10 64-Bit

Bluetooth will not turn on

Moving the settings slider to on, still reflects turned off there and the bt control in the upper right pull down menu shows " turn bt off"

As reflected in the attached ss

Still a bit of a nub with ubuntu however nothing like this with several prior win10/20.04  dual boot installs

Any wisdom greatly appreciated

---

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
Subsystem: Dell 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [1028:0494]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200  Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d]  (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries  BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300 [1028:0010]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure  Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd   Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate  Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2802 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate  Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Added results as requested ...not sure how to edit the question .....content/context/other?